# app registration

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-application

I have an app that I only want my company's employees to use.  It will be available in the Apple and Android App store.  I am trying to figure out a way to secure it so that only the employees can log onto it.

Currently it is set up to accept a company email at registration and sends an email containing an activation link.  I feel like there should be a better way of doing this that does not involve the use of email.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

Also, this app is currently a prototype in the company, so I do not have access to employee ids and such as of now.

Comment: Just put the apk on the company's intranet somewhere.

Comment: i'm using C2DM/GCM registratrion on our server ... first run: i'm only getting user device ID and his google account email ... then she/he have to wait until i authorized (if he run app before it it not show any of Activity because app check on server if user+device is autorized) if i did autorization user can use my app ... having C2DM/GCM has another advantage... i can send remote wipe signal to my app (to delete proprietary data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put them in the stores. Google may allow it, but Apple at least is likely to reject an internal-only app.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

For Android, you can just provide a .apk to download.

Comment: it's a pitty that Google didn't do the same ... providing updates for non Play's app is really pain in the a... but still registration is needed as someone unauthorized can get apk ...

Answer (score 2):

For IOS, there are two ways:

1. Get an IOS enterprise developer account which will allow you to develop and distribute apps without placing them in the app store.  I haven't done it, but from what I remember you can deliver them internally from a web server.

   see https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/
2. The manual way is for every person to send you the UID of their device and for you to manually register it in the developer portal, you can send them the app and then they can install it in itunes.  I have found this to work pretty well on a mac but it is unreliable when the user is on windows (go figure ...)

Comment: Note that #2 has a max of 100 devices. Fo a large business, that's not going to work.

Comment: @ceejayoz #2 will work with an enterprise license. it costs $299 vs $99. but you can have unlimited devices.

Comment: @mkral #2 is presented in this answer as an alternative to an enterprise license. If used as an alternative, the 100 limit applies.

Comment: @ceelayoz, sorry I must have skipped over #1 what you were saying, but you can still distribute the IPA manually with an enterprise account using an ad-hoc build.

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate things. Download some simple xml file from a server, together with the updated apk file if the current version is older.

Then prompt the user to install the new one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```